# Class instance list

Tags: python, list, class, instance

I'd like to create a video class in order to manage the collection of a personal video site.

```
class video:
...
```

And, each time a video is instantiated, I'd like to add it in a video_list.

What is the best practice (pros and cons of each method)?

Should I use a module global variable video_list:

```
video_list=[]
class video:
    def __init__(self):
        video_list.append(self)
```

Should I use a class variable:

```
class video:
    video_list=[]
    def __init__(self):
        video.video_list.append(self)
```

Or even something else I am not aware of?

Moreover once this list is full, how to empty it?
`del(video.video_list[:])` may empty the list, but instances will still be alive.
Should I then:

```
for video in video.video_list:
    del(video)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would use the class variable.  Proposal for being conform to SO:  Ask for advantages and disadvantages for the various proposals.  Otherwise it looks like asking for opinions which is off-topic here.  And please use `video.video_list.append(self)`.

Comment: `__init__(self):` => `def __init__(self):` for starters

Comment: `for video in video.video_list: del(video)` is nonsense, that just assigns the objects to variable `video` and then deletes **that variable** (not the objects).

Comment: @StefanPochmann ok understood! what is the way to delete each instance that have been created so far? Let's say it differently: is there's a need in term of memory saving to delete "old instances"?

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but objects pretty much get deleted automatically when they can't be used anymore. If some video object is referenced by some outside variable or so, then you can't delete it.